# How to find the broken links in azure website which is AAD enabled?

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have a website which has more broken links and I hosted this website in azure website by enabling AAD authentication.

Also i have a console app with below method to validate the pages broken links.

```
 public bool IsPageBroken(string pageURl)
    {
        bool isValid=true;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pageURl);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            isValid=true;
        }
        else
        {
            isValid=false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

Due to AAD authentication i am getting (401) Unauthorized though i am passing my credentials.

Is there anyway we can resolve this (ignoring the sign-in option)

Thanks,
Saravanan

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a 401 Unauthorized response is because you're trying to authenticate with your web app using CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials. This works for web apps hosted in your corporate domain, but will not work for web apps hosted in Azure.

If you want to call into an AAD-protect web app, you'll need to use [the ADAL libraries](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-libraries/) to obtain a token and attach that token to the Authorization header of your HTTP request.

You can find sample code and some instructions here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless.  Be sure to focus on the client-side instructions since you have already setup and configured your web app with AAD.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your quick reply, i have tried your approach it is working only for WEB api and Web Service and its not working for Web application(asp.net, mvc), Could you please suggest me any other way for by passing AAD authentication for Web Application (MVC, asp.net)

Comment: It should work the same for all HTTP endpoints, web app or web api.  If you're having trouble, I suggest turning on application logs, set it to Informational or Verbose, reproduce the issue, and check the logs to see what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your input, i am able to get the access token after changing the code like below and now i am able access the cloud site urls. Thanks again.

```
do
        {
            retry = false;
            try
            {
                //token = authContext.AcquireToken(todoListResourceId, clientCredential);
                token = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceId, clientId, new Uri("https://mysitename.azurewebsites.net"));
            }
            catch (AdalException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorCode == "temporarily_unavailable")
                {
                    retry = true;
                    retryCount++;
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
            }

        } while ((retry == true) && (retryCount < 3));
        return token;
```